# Applescript to empty trash on external drive

Tags: bash, applescript, erase, recycle-bin

I am writing a script and I am stuck on this one step. I have an external drive, call it disk 1 (with a space in the name). I cannot figure out how to use Applescript to empty just the trash on this drive. I have tried several variations of 
`empty trash of "/Volumes/disk 1/"` and several variations of `do shell script "rm /Volumes/disk1/.Trashes"`, all to no avail.

Even when done, I might find that for my script I am better off just ERASING drive 1 using Disk Utilities. I would also greatly appreciate a script for that.

Comment: The Finder doesn't know about POSIX paths, and when using the shell script you will need to escape the spaces or quote the path.

Comment: The **empty** _verb_ of **Finder** doesn't take a _path_ [specifier], it's “empty” and “empty trash” of which both do the same thing, globally empty the trash.

Comment: On HFS+ and APFS formatted external disks the **.Trashes** permissions are `1333` _octal_ or `d-wx-wx-wt` and with those permissions even if you are the owner, and not `root`, cannot delete it unless the permissions are changed or use `sudo` if done in **Terminal**. That said, one way to delete it in **AppleScript** is to use e.g., `do shell script "rm -r '/path/to/.Trashes'" with administrator privileges` where you'll get a credentials dialog box to allow it to happen as if using `sudo` in **Terminal**. The dialog box is pretty non descriptive though!

Comment: user3439894. Thank you. I made myself owner of disk 1, ran your shell script, & it worked except I must enter a password, and I need this script to work  unattended. I was afraid of something like this. I don't know enough AppleScript, and I don't know any AWK, so could someone please give me AppleScript code to have Disk Utilities erase the disk. I only keep one file on this disk and it takes up over half the space. Thus, in order for my script to update it, it must be deleted first. Since I can't empty the trash, I am happy to just erase the disk and then copy an updated version of the file.

Comment: How is the _file_ been deleted in the first place? Instead of putting the _file_ in the **Trash**, why not just delete the _file_ with `rm`, e.g `do shell script "rm '/path/to/file'"` or `tell application "System Events" to delete disk item "/path/to/file"`; however be very careful as once deleted it cannot be recovered easily, if at all.  Also, making yourself owner of the disk is not as important as making yourself owner of `.Trashes` and even then you have to change it's permissions to delete if if not `root` or using `sudo` or  `do shell script "..." with administrator privileges`.

Comment: Oh. In fact my script uses `do shell script "rm '/path/to/file'"` I haven't yet tested the script on the actual large file, just small temporary ones. If I don't have to empty the trash, then I am set. I'll test the code on the actual large file tomorrow. If this works, how do I give you credit in stack overflow?

Comment: My script is now complete and works as intended. I have a 300 GB file and it apparently has a file structure, so I found that `do shell script "rm -fr '/path/to/file'"` works. I also had to enclose it in a `with timeout of 5400 seconds` structure to allow enough time (about 1/2 hour currently) for the copy to complete. Since user3439894 answered both my original question and the subsequent one, I would like to give him credit but I am not familiar enough with stack overflow to know how to do this.

Comment: Instead of using a timeout, you can just release the shell process as a background task, like so: `do shell script "rm -fr '/path/to/file' &> /dev/null"`. Control will return to the AppleScript immediately, and it can safely exit while the delete process continues on. See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG5-I_WANT_TO_START_A_BACKGROUND_SERVER_PROCESS__HOW_DO_I_MAKE_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_NOT_WAIT_UNTIL_THE_COMMAND_COMPLETES_